# Release .ipa-File as update to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, nativescript

I plan to release my .ipa to iTunes Connect. Since the app is in NativeScript and we are bringing out an update, I referred to this tutorial:

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/releasing-updates-to-your-nativescript-apps-on-the-ios-app-store-and-google-play

which works fine so far, now I want to know, if I need to use the same Apple ID that has been used the last time for the deploy or if this can by any Apple ID? Can anyone share his experience with me? :) It would be great if this would work with another Apple ID, but I cannot inmagine this tbh.

Comment: Can you explain what are your referring to apple id here ?

Comment: your question is not clear!

Comment: I mean the id I need to log in with (basically when I visit https://itunesconnect.apple.com/login )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, If you want to submit application update then you can not use different developer account because your app was registered with that apple developer account! So, in new account you will not find your existing app then how can you submit the update? If you want to release your project(your .ipa) as a new application then you can use any apple developer id! but if you want to submit an update then you must need same developer account!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I also thought, but I was hoping it was possible somehow :)

Comment: I know this is perhaps not part of the question, but I am supposed to add the `UUID` manually on the `--provision` element (and, since my build.xcconfig does not specify a `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` nor a `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY`, those also) when building the new release. But I cannot make out where to find it. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: I am not getting what you are asking! And you should ask another question if it is not related the current question as per SO's guidelines!